# What unit is MongoDB's location indexing in? Meters? Miles?

Tags: python, mongodb, geolocation, database

```
db.posts.ensureIndex({"loc":"2d"})
```

If I do that and query by it...

What are the units?

```
db.posts.find({"loc": {"$within": {"$center" : [ user_center, user_radius ] }}})
```

What if I want to find something 5 miles away, what would my radius be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your unit is whatever you store there. If you store in degrees on a globe that will be your unit for a `$within`.

If you use degrees then the `$within` for 5 miles will be ~ 0.07 since a degree is 60 nautical miles.

Comment: I don't know...that's all I did. I store it as a lat/long coordinate, and I ran that index. Can you tell me what do i do?

Comment: try to use 0.07 as the distance in the `$within` and see if those results are what you expect

Comment: 60 nautical miles ~ 69 miles so I would use `n / 69`

Comment: But that gets wrong sometimes. It's off when I scale up the number of miles.

Comment: yeah .. it will get more wrong as you travel farther from the equator. That is a rough estimate as it is only truly accurate at the equator.

Comment: This may help you get more precise when starting from a point on the globe http://www.meridianworlddata.com/Distance-Calculation.asp